# Import contacts into dada mail

Tags: mailing-list

I have a csv file with all my contact...I need to import them into DADAMAIL without the need to send people an invitation...as they where yet subscribed  with the previous phplist
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use the option Subscribers->Invite and then select White List instead os Subscribers. This way you will add the subscribers directly without invitation.